# How do i get my html button to stay clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, browser

How can i maintain the `:active` selector's css even after the click without changing the browser's default `:active` selector's css for the button.

Comment: No enough information to help you. Sorry

Comment: I think you haven't tried what you are stating here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either rely on the `:active` pseudo class via css and style it accordingly or use JavaScript to set a css class on the click event to add a css class that is styled like in the mousedown state.

You may also look how bootstrap did this on their example page:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

Answer (score 3):

You could style the 'active' and the 'visited' attributes of your button to look the same.

```
#button:active{
    border:1 px solid red;
    color:#FFF;
    background:black;
}
#button:visited{
    border:1 px solid red;
    color:#FFF;
    background:black;
}
```

Be sure to give your button an id.